# How to save multiple images in a single TIFF file in python

Tags: python, image, save, glob, tiff

I have multiple images I want to save each 22 images in TIFF file. I used glob to store 22 images the to save them in a TIFF single file . I store 22 images in `filenames` using `glob`

```
for i, ci in enumerate(coefficients):
        plt.imshow(ci.reshape(1, -1), extent=[0, 3844, i + 0.5, i +1.5], cmap='inferno', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')
        plt.ylim(0.5, len(coeffs)-0.5) 
        plt.yticks(range(1, len(coeffs)), ['cD5', 'cD4', 'cD3', 'cD2', 'cD1'])  
    plt.axis('off')
        plt.savefig(FirstPartPathOutput+SecondPartPathOutput+'/spec_'+isPreictal+'_'+str(nSpectogram+1)+'_'+str(k)+'.png')
    legendOfOutput=legendOfOutput+' '+str(nSpectogram+1)+' '+str(k) +' '+SecondPartPathOutput+'/spec_'+isPreictal+'_'+str(nSpectogram+1)+'_'+str(k) +'.png\n'
    if k==21:
        filenames = glob.glob(FirstPartPathOutput+SecondPartPathOutput+'/spec_'+isPreictal+'_'+str(nSpectogram+1)+'_'+str(k) + "/*.png")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the error/problem in your code?

Comment: @Alderven I want to save each tiff file in this name `FirstPartPathOutput+SecondPartPathOutput+'/spec_'+isPreictal+'_'+str(nSpectogram+1)+'_'+str(k) + "/*.png"` How I can do that ??